# Cadena de números con for. JAVA BASICO

Tags: java, bucle-for, bucles, algoritmos

Buenas noches soy nuevo en esto y quería saber como imprimir una cadena de texto y que cada vez que se escriba se guarde el valor anterior y se vuelva a imprimir hasta esta linea. como por ejemplo
1
1 2
1 2 3
...
1 2 3 4 5 ... numero

En este programa el problema que hay esque solo se me imprime asi:
1
2
3
...
numero

Creo que me falta otro bucle dentro del mismo for, pero no se cual es la condicion.

```
    int numero, inicio = 1;
    Scanner escaner;
    escaner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Escribeme un numero: ");
    numero = escaner.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
        System.out.println(inicio, inicio);
        inicio++;
    }
```

Comment: Entonces siempre estarìa pidiendo un valor, al ingresarlo imprimirìa este valor y el anterior.

Comment: Hola, explica mejor tu ejemplo; no llego a entender bien lo que quieres

Answer (score 0):

tendrias que hacerlo con dos for

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class prueba{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
                
                int i,j,n;
                System.out.print("Ingresa un numero: ");
                Scanner escaner = new Scanner(System.in);
                n = escaner.nextInt();
    
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
                {
                for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
                System.out.print(String.valueOf(j+" "));
    
                }
                }
                }
```

Comment: Esta bien pero el unico fallo que me ha dado es que se imprime todo en la misma linea.

Comment: Utliza System.out.println en vez de System.out.print

Comment: tu ejemplo de pregunta se encuentra asi.....si quieres en fila cambia print por println si quieres que se imprima en modo piramide coloca : System.out.print(String.valueOf(j));
                System.out.println("");

Answer (score 0):

Al pasar unas horas he visto que se hace asi con un .valueOf que coje el valor anterior y le añade mas uno al siguiente por el for.

```
    int numeroDeUsuario;
    String lista = "";
    Scanner escaner;
    escaner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Escribeme un numero : ");
    numeroDeUsuario = escaner.nextInt();
    numeroDeUsuario ++;

    escaner.close();    

    for (int i = 1; i < numeroDeUsuario; i++) {
        lista = lista + " " + String.valueOf(i);
        System.out.println(lista);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

O tambien podemos haclero de una forma mas facil con dos bucles.

```
    int numeroDeUsuario;
    Scanner escaner;
    escaner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Escribeme un numero : ");
    numeroDeUsuario = escaner.nextInt();

    escaner.close();    

    for (int i = 1; i <= numeroDeUsuario; i++) {
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            System.out.print(j+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }      
}
```

}

Comment: tu consulta dice cadena.....